# How can I perform a dynamic search in MongoDB and nodejs? (I have around 20 fields to search which could be extensible)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection in the MongoDB as `userRegister` having fields like `name`, `age`, `mobileno`, `email`, ...`activityViewed`, etc...

Where `userid` is primary key and auto-generated by the MongoDB.

How can I make the search like all over those 20 fields in nodejs?

I had tried indexes on MongoDB but it won't work it just give me one column to search... (As indexes)